# Counting the sum of digits in a loop

Tags: c++, c, count, sum, digits

I have a problem making an algorithm count the sum of digits that were used in a loop.

Let me outline the basic principles :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 9 Digits
>    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 = 11 Digits

I have try to search for a solution for a bit, but I could not find a solution that would be suitable.

The base idea is that I have a known number n that will represent the end of the digit count.
Count begins from 1 so `1 <= n <= 10000`.

The first thing that came to my mind was counting the digit amount:

```
while(numdig != 0) {
    numDig = n/10;
    digCount++;
}
```

and continue on with a loop in a loop but I found myself confused on the second loop . After that I thought of a cycle that would use a lot of if`s which would be a very incorrect way of solving the problem.

I hope the problem is understandable.
Thank you

Comment: You have the hard part, iterate the numbers and use you code to count the digits. `digCount = 0; for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { int numDig = i; /*you while loop here*/ }`

Comment: I wonder if there is a simple solution using `stringstream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will prove useful (separating the digit counting into its own function) in helping you write your program.

```
/* return the number of digits in the number i */
int ndigits ( int i ) {
    int n = 1;

    if (i < 0) i = -i;
    while (i >= 10) { ++n; i /= 10; }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: There would be a way to optimize this over the brute force way of counting the number of digits in each of the numbers.  0-9 each have 1, 10-99 each have 2, 100-999 each have 3, etc.  So, if the number is greater than 100, you know you have 9 total for 1-9, plus 1800 for 100-999 (900 numbers times 2 digits each), and so on.

Comment: Thanks, a function might really help in this case

Comment: Note: this approach fails on a corner case of `INT_MIN`.  To deal with that: `if (i > 0) i = -i; while (i <= -10) { ++n; i /= 10; }`.  +1 anyways

Comment: @chux `1 <= n <= 10000`

Comment: It might be a stupid question, but Im not sure why are we using if (i < 0) i = -i;  What error could happen if I didnt put it there? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: It's handling the case where the input is negative (which is actually outside the scope of your original question, but something to be thought about in general).  On most machines there is an additional corner case complication -- signed integer variables hold one more negative number than they hold positive ones.  For example, a signed 8-bit number goes from -128 to 127.  So, if you try to change the sign of -128 to 128 you will not get 128, because 128 doesn't fit  The most negative number your machine can hold in an int is called INT_MIN -- that's what that comment above was about.

Answer (score 3):

You can try use `snprintf`( which returns the number of characters that were written). Would be something like:

```
//read numdig
char buff[6]; // max of 5 digits and the '\0'
digCount += snprintf(buff,6, "%d", numdig);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it very useful :) I never heard about snprintf before

Comment: <cstdio> (<stdio.h>)  have some very useful functions for things like this =)

Comment: Problems 1) Should be `snprintf(buff,6, "%d", numdig);` or better `snprintf(buff,sizeof buff, "%d", numdig);` 2) Why so small, maybe `char buff[22];` 3) off by one for negative numbers.  max of 5 character, not digits, and the '\0'

Comment: I fixed problem #1, thanks. I've just used the right amount of chars for the problem that was proposed and there is no negative numbers ( 1 <= n <= 10000). 

And I think 'digit' isn't a wrong term as numbers are formed by combination of digits

Comment: true for the range  (1 <= n <= 10000), no negative numbers and `buff[6]` is sufficient.   As others from time-to-time skim through the posts & answers, they do not see the limited usefulness of a given answer.  char vs. digit makes sense when considering `'-'`.  My comments part 2 & 3 do not detract from the correctness of your answer for the post's limited range.  +1

Answer (score 1):

This could be another approach

```
int getDigitCount ( int val )
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << val;
   string valstr = ss.str ();
   return valstr.length();
}


int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
   int n;
   cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 10000 " << endl;
   cin >> n;
   long digitcount = 0;
   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i ++ )
   {
      digitcount += getDigitCount ( i );
   }

   cout << "Digit Count =" << digitcount << endl;
   return 0;
}
```